# How to restore a tensorflow model that only has one file with extension ".model"

Tags: tensorflow, restore, pre-trained-model

I want to use a pretrained tensorflow model provided by an unknown author. I do not know how he/she managed to save the tensorflow model (he/she used tensorflow version >= 1.2) to only one file with the extension '**.model**', as normally I get either three files '.meta', '.data', '.index' or one file with '.ckpt'.

How can I restore this pretrained model? How can I save a model to this format later?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have also asked this question on a number of platforms with no assistance yet. So I  decided to do some experimental work and this is what I found. This may be long but please bear with me.

To import a model in Tensor-flow we use

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_test_model-1000.meta')
  new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

The `.meta` file contains all the variables, operations, collections, etc, of the trained model. What `tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./')` does is to use the checkpoint file (which simply keeps a record of latest checkpoint files saved) to import the `xxxx_model.data-00000-of-00001`. This `.data-00000-of-00001` contains all the weights, biases, gradients, etc, that must be loaded into the variables contained in `my_test_model-1000.meta`.

### Summary [Semi-complete code]

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_test_model-1000.meta')
    #new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    tensor_variable = tf.trainable_variables()
    for tensor_var in tensor_variable:
        #print(sess.run(tensor_var))
        print(tensor_var)
```

This initial code will print out all the variables from `.meta` that are trainable. If you try to run `print(sess.run(tensor_var))` you will get an error. This is because, the variables have not been initialized. How ever, if you un-comment `new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))` and run `print(sess.run(tensor_var))`, you will get all the variables alongside values loaded into the variables.

---

### Now to “.model”

My best guess is that `xxxxxx.model` works a much like `xxxx_model.data-00000-of-00001` from tensorflow. It does not contain variables and so if you try to do

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
          new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('xxx.model')
```

you will get an error. Remember, the reason is that, this `.model` file does not contain any variables nor operation graph of any form. If you also try to do

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
          new_saver = tf.train.Saver()
          new_saver.restore(sess, "xxxx.model")
```

you will similarly get an error. This is because, there are no corresponding variables to load values into. Therefore, if you ever obtain a `xxx.model` file, you will have to go through the pain of replicating all the variables and operations before trying to run `new_saver.restore(sess, "xxxx.model")`. If you are able to replicate the architecture, this will run smoothly with no issues, hopefully.

I am sorry this was long, but considering that there is almost no answer on the internet, I had to make a lecture out of it. :)

Comment: How can use this model to predict something? I have got three files for word embedding, namely **word2vec_model.model**, **word2vec_model.model.syn1neg.npy** and **word2vec_model.model.wv.syn0.npy**. Now, I am confused how to use this files.

Comment: @ProtikNag do you have the meta file? If you don't, you will have to construct the model architecture first before you can load your models. I am also not quite sure what the content of the .npy files are so I am afraid I will need some more details to be able to provide some suggestions.